# Удаление элемента из списка

Tags: память, структуры, c++, список

Функция должна удалять элемент структуры (однонаправленного линейного списка) по идентификатору. Идентификатор элемента структуры обозначается `lid`, с клавиатуры вводится идентификатор удаляемого элемента `id`. `first` - ссылка на первый элемент списка.
Если элемента с таким идентификатором не существует, функция должна вернуть `false`.
Функция, написанная мной, возвращает `false` всегда, а если список состоит из одного элемента, ругает меня за глупость грязными словами. Какова причина такого её поведения?

```
bool delel1 (lin* first, int id) {
    lin *cur; 
    cur=first;
    bool pus=false;
do {
        if  (cur->lid==id) {
            pus=true; break;
        }
    cur=cur->next; 
} while (cur==NULL);
if (pus==false) cout << "Элемент не существует\n";
else {
    lin* p=cur->next;
    delete cur;
    cur=p;
    if (cur==0) {first=0; cur=first;}
    }
return (pus);
}
```

Comment: @Марис Мистраль, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 3):

Обратите внимание на условие :

> > while (cur==NULL);

Мне кажется, там должно стоять "!="
Т.е. если Вы не передаете в функцию пустой список, в текущем варианте цикл не выполнится ни одного раза.

Answer (score 2):

[@Марис Мистраль](/users/10609/%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%81-%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C), [@margosh](/users/6966/margosh) точно указала Вам на одну из ошибок (описку?).

А еще, если `first == NULL` , то в `if  (cur->lid==id)` все грохнется.

Обычно пишут примерно так

```
for (pus = false, cur = first; cur; cur = cur->next) {
   if  (cur->lid == id) ...
}
```

И еще, если Вы хотите изменить first в **вызывающей** программе, то его либо надо передавать по ссылке, либо передавать его адрес. Лично я предпочитаю передачей по ссылке не пользоваться, т.к. в вызывающей программе непосредственно по виду вызова непонятно, может ли аргумент измениться.

А конкретно этот фрагмент я бы написал так

```
bool 
delel1 (lin **pfirst, int id)
{
    lin *cur = *pfirst,  // элемент, который будем удалять
        *p = NULL;       // элемент перед cur
    while (cur && cur->lid != id) {
        p = cur;
        cur = cur->next;
    }
    if (cur) {    // нашли
        if (p)    // и пред ним есть элементы списка
            p->next = cur->next;
        else      // он был первым, обновим указатель на список
            *pfirst = cur->next; // если cur был единственным, то список станет пустым
        delete cur;
        return true;
    }
    if (*pfirst)
       cout << "Элемент " << id << " не найден\n";
    else
       cout << "Список пуст\n";
    return false;
}
```

Прямо скажу, не тестировал, проверял только компиляцию

```
typedef struct elem {
  struct elem *next;
  int         lid;
} lin;
```

с таким вот объявлением `lin` и

```
int
main ()
{
  lin *first = NULL;

  delel1(&first,12);

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Имхо, так понтовей. Если разобраться в магии - скилл повышается на 100.

```
uint8_t remove_elem(elem ** in, uint32_t id) {

    elem * prev, * first = *in;

    while((prev = first) && (first->lid != id) && ((first = first->next) != NULL)); //магия

    if(!first) return 0;//Может быть в 2-х случаях: 1) нам подсунули NULL; 2) елемента тупо нет.

    if(prev == first) //Нашли елемент - он первый.
        *in = first->next; //сдвигаем первый елемент
     else //Он не первый.
        prev->next = first->next; //Выкидываем тот, который нашли

    free(first);
    return 1;
}
```

Вроде ничего не напутал. По поводу кода из вопроса автора - слишком много всякой лишней и непонятной записи. Надо писать попроще - тогда проще разобраться, не привыкать писать (p == NULL) и т.п. Вообщем надо не лениться и сидеть часок-другой над кодом, чтобы хорошо вкурить задачу.

Comment: У вас в первом `while` значение `prev` неинициализировано. Насколько повысился мой скилл? :-P

Comment: @VladD, скилл упал (там же коммент - **магия**). 

Инициализация проводится первым присваиванием, проверяется его результат, если присвоили NULL, то while не исполняется.

@o2n3e, ничего не скажешь, красиво.

Магия - фигня, а вот совместить первый с предыдущим - это мне понравилось.

Comment: @avp: а, и правда, перепутал `=` с `==` :-)

Comment: А вообще - это бида. Если запилить пулец на 100500*100500 елементов списка и юзать не маллок, а id заменить оффестом, то удаление елемента будет летать.


Толи люди не привыкли, что у теперешних amd64 виртуальных адресов может быть на овер10бит больше, чем он может физически адресовать рамы. И что на самом деле на amd64 манагер кучи с рандомными кусками вообще не нужен.


Толи это осталось от прошлой 32битной x86 архитектуры.


Вобщем - это пичально, тупая, бренная совместимость.

Comment: @o2n3e, это Вы серьезно? 

А если все так начнут, свопа на серваке хватит? А про pageout не думали, ОС-то не знает, что модифицированные странички больше никому не нужны.

Хотя, может я не так понял. Вы наверное хотите повторно использовать однотипные структуры из пула, провязать  их в список свободных и выдавать-возвращать?

Comment: @avp, да.

Зачем на сервере своп? madvise+mmap = никаких проблем.



Я говорю вообще обо всём. Есть 2 подхода к созданию "структур" неопределённой длинны в куче: 1) malloc()/realoc(), 2) анонимный mmap() на 10-20гигов. Я за второй способ.


Фейл первого подхода заключается ещё в том, что malloc(4) != (malloc(4)-4) - это не даёт делать очень хитрые и быстрее штуки. 



Да, эти фейлы почти на 80% нивелируются всякими пуллами и etc. И то, это делают почти никто. 



В основном почти весь код, особенно stl/C++ - это насилование malloc()'a, что меня удручает.

Comment: @o2n3e, а понты-то гнилые. 

Грызло меня что-то, грызло, взял да и проверил. "Магия" с `while` не работает. 

В самом же деле (*позор на мою лысину, сразу должен был увидеть*) в начале **каждого** цикла делаете `prev = first`, а потом сравнение first->lid с id. 

Резюме - когда нашли id, то **prev == first** и значит отрезаем все начало списка.  


Если вместо Вашего `while` написать

    for (prev = first; first && first->lid != id; prev = first,first = first->next);

то все остальное работает.

--

Про выделение гигабайт памяти  и пэйджинг, если интересно, еще поговорим (место кончилось...)